# python, histogram,data fitting

Tags: python, histogram

I wish to make a Histogram in Python 3 from an input file containing the raw data of energy (.dat). And on the same plot I want to plot a formula(distribution analytical, pho vs energy). It is easy to plot them seperately, but I need combined version. Can you help?

Comment: have you tried `matplotlib.pyplot.subplot` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want 2 plots in the same figure look into this:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/subplots_demo.html

`fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2)`

If you want to have 2 plots int he same plot that share axis use this:
https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/gallery/subplots_axes_and_figures/two_scales.html#sphx-glr-gallery-subplots-axes-and-figures-two-scales-py

`ax2 = ax1.twinx()  # instantiate a second axes that shares the same x-axis`